# How do I silently request a specific SSL client certificate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, ssl, client-certificates

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 site that uses forms authentication, but is also using client certificates for an added layer of security by setting:

```
<security>
    <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />
</security>
```

The client certificate is optional because it isn't required until the user actually attempts to log into the site. When the user attempts to log in, the site will validate the Thumbnail, Issuer, and compare the Subject to the user attempting to log in (there will be a different certificate per user).The problem is that every time a user comes to the site they are prompted to provide a client certificate when they first enter the site, which may cause issues if:

- they accidentally select the wrong certificate
- want to log off & log back in with a different user (not re-prompted for a cert)

Is there a way to silently\automatically detect a client certificate based on the log-in provided rather than having the user select a certificate on first entering the site?

**EDIT**: Adding more specific example of Actual\Desired behavior

Actual Behavior:

- User opens up Chrome and goes to http://www.example.com
- Chrome pop-up asks user what client certificate they want to use
- User chooses "**user3** (www.example.com)"
- User sees unauthenticated home page view & clicks the "Log In" button
- User enters Username: "**user2**" and Password: "********"
- Site validates that ClientCertificate.Subject == Username (fails because certificate is for "user3")

Desired Behavior:

- User opens up Chrome and goes to http://www.example.com
- User sees unauthenticated home page view & clicks the "Log In" button
- User enters Username: "**user2**" and Password: "********"
- Browser *does something* to silently detect if client has certificate "**user2** (www.example.com)" with little to no user interaction

  **Question**: Is the "Desired Behavior" possible in some way? (header? javascript? browser plug-in?)

Comment: You could add a friendly name with the user's identity and search that way.

Comment: You might also have a look at this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742438.aspx Step-by-Step Guide to Mapping Certificates to User Accounts The article is old but should still be able to figure something out from it

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually not having an issue with the mapping, but just the order in which the certificate -> log in is provided. I'll update my question to explain better...

Comment: Just wondering why you'd think it's necessary to have both client-cert authentication and username+password. Considering that you seem to suggest your users may also have multiple valid identities for the same site as well, this sounds a bit too complicated for most requirements...

Comment: Having both user\pass & certificate adds a 2nd layer of security (aka, what the user knows & what the user has). We'll likely put the certificate on a smart card to make it more transportable, but we don't want just username\password or the smart card alone to be enough to allow access. They'll need both.

Comment: Usually, the 2 factors in this sort of authentication are: what the user has (the smart card) and what the user knows (the PIN code to unlock the smart card). What you'd be introducing here would be a 3rd factor. Not sure how many users would be patient enough for that (often, when users find security measures too cumbersome, they do whatever they can to bypass them, which may be worse than what you're trying to achieve). If you really want a server-side password, it might be worth implementing a system that just asks the password, getting the username from the certificate.

Comment: That's a great point. I had totally forgotten that smart cards require pins. I wasn't prepared to put our data's security in the hands of a single technology, but I'll have to give this some thought... Thanks!

I wish I could up-vote your comment twice. The concept of getting the username from the cert & having them enter their own password is a great idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, and due to security issues, there is no way to select a certificate for the user at all when he is visiting a website.

The user can configure their browser to use a specific certificate for a website by default if he wants, but that's a different thing.

For the second part, the certificate is used to secure the connection between the browser (client) and the server, so if you want to use another certificate you should entirely finish the connection between the browser and the server, unfortunately you would need to close the browser and open it again for that to happen in most cases. Or by cleaning the certificate cache, but that needs to be done manually by the user in his browser.

You can find a very good explanation about how certificates and SSL works here:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work

Comment: @Buno  if you rean the sentence again you will see that it means that only the user can select the certificate, you cannot programatically select a certificate for the user from a website. Is simply not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to do this within a single application. One way to do it is to create two asp.net-mvc applications.  The second site would be a sub-directory application with the `SslNegotiateCert` in the sub-directory's `web.config` and contain all the secure methods/logins etc.